# Проверка на null. С получением исключения NullReferenceException

Tags: c#

Код немного упростил, чтоб все сюда не пихать но смысл следующий.
Массив modules инициализировал статично. Там по сути около 28 элементов.
Этот массив принимает в себя объекты вложенного класса где по полю module не выделена память.

Мне бы хотелось бы проверить module на равность или неравность null, чтобы определить занята ли ячейка в массиве. То есть проверка на null здесь должна быть... Или мне придется проверять не равенство c null, а выдачу исключения, что по сути проще. В общем странность какая то, в С++ такое бы конечно же сработало бы...

```
public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler {

    private class ModuleObject {
        public GameObject module;
        // прочие поля...
    }

    private ModuleObject[] modules; // Список перенесенных модулей на слоты.
    private int CurrentIndex = 0;

    void OnStart(){
        modules = new ModuleObject[50];

        if (modules[CurrentIndex].module != null) { // Вот тут вот ошибка, что объекту не задана ссылка
            CurrentIndex = (CurrentIndex + 1 < 50) ? CurrentIndex : 0;
            for(int i=0; i < 50; ++i) {
                if (modules[i].module == null) {
                    CurrentIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После

```
modules = new ModuleObject[50];
```

все элементы массива равны `null`.

```
if (modules[CurrentIndex] == null)
  modules[CurrentIndex] = new ModuleObject();

if (modules[CurrentIndex].module != null) {
  ...
```

Comment: Да я чет совсем затупил блин... Вот это надо было сравнивать modules[CurrentIndex] 
А не modules[CurrentIndex].module =)) Ну ладно спасибо. Не ну это просто стыд испанский